# When using file to read data and writing file, I can't attain the correct anwser, but when I debug, it works nice

Tags: c++, file-read

It's about a prediction of house price using regression analysis.
The main of question is, when I set a break point at the end of the code, I can see the answer, but when I run it, it returns error codes.
I had changed the way to read the file, but it not works well.
Please point the error of mine.

```cpp
#include<cstdio>
#include<cstring>
#include<cmath>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;
struct Data{
    double feature[15];//特征值的数据
};
Data data[520];
struct Connct{
    double connect;//和最后房价的相关性
    int id;
}link[13];
double weight[15];//对应特征值的权重
//每个特征值对应的求和---对每个特征值用最小二乘法
double sumX[15];
double sumXY[15];
double sumXX[15];
double sumY=0.00;
double sumY2=0.00;
double besides=0.00;
int cmp(Connct x,Connct y){//返回较大的关联值
    return x.connect>=y.connect;
}
int main(){
    freopen("house.txt","r",stdin);
    //freopen("123.txt","w",stdout);

    for(int i=0;i<506;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<14;j++){
            scanf("%lf",&data[i].feature[j]);
        }
    }
    preprocess();//归一化处理
    //求和
    for(int i=0;i<506;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<13;j++){
            sumX[j]+=data[i].feature[j];
            sumXX[j]=sumXX[j]+data[i].feature[j]*data[i].feature[j];
            sumXY[j]=sumXY[j]+data[i].feature[j]*data[i].feature[13];
        }
        sumY+=data[i].feature[13];
        sumY2=sumY2+data[i].feature[13]*data[i].feature[13];
    }
    //对每一维度使用最小二乘法，计算出权重计算相关性
    for(int i=0;i<13;i++){
        weight[i]=(sumXY[i]-sumX[i]*sumY/506)/(sumXX[i]-sumXX[i]/506);
        link[i].connect=(506*sumXY[i]-sumX[i]*sumY)/(sqrt(506*sumXX[i]-sumX[i]*sumX[i])*sqrt(506*sumY2-sumY*sumY));
        link[i].id=i;
    }
    //找出最相关的三个因素
    sort(link,link+13,cmp);
    //处理，计算出偏置
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
        besides+=weight[link[i].id]*sumX[link[i].id];
        printf("%lf ",weight[link[i].id]);
    }
    besides=(sumY-besides)/506;
    printf("\n%lf",besides);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: process function has been detele, please ignore it,or when you copy this code ,detele it.

Comment: `cmp` doesn't meet the requirements of a strict weak ordering, and so `std::sort` call using it exhibits undefined behavior.

Comment: first in the `cmp`, using compare return true or false to sort it,it often work well,                  then I has used the `using namespace std`,I can using `sort` to run the funcation of `std::sort`

Comment: The main problem of this code is that the answer of the debug is different with the answer of run.

Comment: `The main problem of this code is that the answer of the debug is different with the answer of run` well that's one effect undefined behavior can have. You have to fix everything that causes undefined behavior and it will create the same result in debug and release.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been solved by detele the funcation of freopen.After I detele it, the answer of debug is same as run. Prehaps the freopen has some secrets usage which I don't know.